# Spring mvc controller won't redirect to the right jsp page

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

So I have this on my landing.jsp

```
    <div class="nav-right nav-menu" id="nav-menu">
      <a class="nav-item is-hidden-tablet is-active roboto strong letter-space-1" href="toLoginPage.action">HOME</a>
      <a class="nav-item is-hidden-tablet roboto strong letter-space-1" href="about.action"/>"> ABOUT </a>
      <a class="nav-item is-hidden-tablet roboto strong letter-space-1" href="contact.html"> CONTACT </a>
      <a class="nav-item roboto strong letter-space-1" id="login-btn"> LOGIN </a>
    </div>
```

So what I'm trying to do is when I am on the landing page (landing.jsp), I want the user to be able to navigate to the about page by clicking on the navbar of the landing page. But aparrently, it wont switch jsp's

here is my controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value="toLoginPage")
@ResponseBody
public String toNewLoginPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

    Cookie[] cookieArr=request.getCookies();
    if(cookieArr==null) {
            return "login/landing";
    }
    for(Cookie cookie:cookieArr){
        System.out.println(cookie.getName());
        if(cookie.getName().equals("userInfo")){
            String userIdStr=cookie.getValue();
            long userId=Long.parseLong(userIdStr);
            UserBean userBean=userService.getUserById(userId);
            HttpSession session=request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute(Constant.SESSION_USER, userBean.getId()+"");
            if(userBean.getIsActive()==1){
                session.setAttribute(Constant.SESSION_IS_ACTIVE, true);
            }else{
                session.setAttribute(Constant.SESSION_IS_ACTIVE, false);
            }
            request.setAttribute("MsgModuleUrl", CurisConfig.CurisConfig.MODULE_ADDRESS.MsgModule);
            request.setAttribute("formula", CurisConfig.CurisConfig.MODULE_ADDRESS.CurisForum);
            return "index/index";
        }
    }

    //compare the servlet request url and redirect to 
    return "login/landing";

}

    @RequestMapping(value="about")
public ModelAndView aboutPage(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

    Cookie[] cookieArr=request.getCookies();
    if(cookieArr==null) {
            return new ModelAndView("login/landing");
    }
    for(Cookie cookie:cookieArr){
        System.out.println(cookie.getName());
        if(cookie.getName().equals("userInfo")){
            String userIdStr=cookie.getValue();
            long userId=Long.parseLong(userIdStr);
            UserBean userBean=userService.getUserById(userId);
            HttpSession session=request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute(Constant.SESSION_USER, userBean.getId()+"");
            if(userBean.getIsActive()==1){
                session.setAttribute(Constant.SESSION_IS_ACTIVE, true);
            }else{
                session.setAttribute(Constant.SESSION_IS_ACTIVE, false);
            }
            request.setAttribute("MsgModuleUrl", CurisConfig.CurisConfig.MODULE_ADDRESS.MsgModule);
            request.setAttribute("formula", CurisConfig.CurisConfig.MODULE_ADDRESS.CurisForum);
            return new ModelAndView("index/index");
        }
    }

    return new ModelAndView("login/about");
}
```

So you can see that I was somehow inconsistent with how I return request but I was trying to see if the ModelAndView would work because the String implementation wouldn't. The

Comment: What is the question? Do you see any errors? Is the controller invoked?

Comment: the controller is invoked it's just that it won't redirect to the about.jsp. It always stays on the landing.jsp

Comment: What is the View Resolver Configuration you did in Dispatcher Servlet?

Comment: oh no I dont know how to make it a code

Comment: '<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass"
    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>'

@Arunkumar

Comment: Have you checked the cookieArr? If it's null you always redirect to landing.jsp.

Comment: you are returning  **login/about** so make sure that **about** jsp file is inside the folder **/WEB-INF/jsp/login**

Comment: thank you @RubioRic, that fixed the problem

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help. :-)